# How can i nest child components in next js like react outlet?

Tags: next.js, nested-routes, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm a react JS developer and trying to create nested childrens in nextjs. In react i used the outlet to nest the child components but how can i nest child in next js.

`Folder Structure:`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF32k.png

`Index.js:`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1v8U.png

As you can see the indexpage, there is a navbar. When i click on about it change the route. But i don't want to change the route. I want to render the content of about on the same page under the navbar. And on on click of projects and blogs i want to change the route and on that route i want different navbar not like the index.js navbar.And on blog page i want a sidebar which containes links whenever i click on specific link the specific page will render on right of sidebar (outlet thing). I'm new to it is there a way to do this

I gone through the documentation and also read articles on it. Is there a way nest child components in a parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

move about.js outside pages folder, and import it on the page you want to render it, you can set in state, when user click about and render the about page